# Customize Openam Login page

Tags: openam

I want to customize OpenAm login page, for client perspective, 
I had check OpenaAm Chapter for latest  XUI changes, ie by default it takes XUI
I tried to configure current default theme, 
present in

XUI/themeConfig.json under the directory where we unpack OpenAM,

For example.
I had modify footer element : by default footer mailto element: info@forgerock.com

```
    "footer": {
                "mailto": "info@xyz.com",
                "phone": ""
             }
         }
```

after pack and deploy war file,

But still it showing old one ie info@forgerock.com on startup

My question is what is the proper steps of customizing OpenAm login page , from OpenAm guide, it was bit confusing.

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)Modify **XUI\config\themeConfig.json**, delete cache from your web browser...Then reload page and see what you had entered.

b)You can also set *org.forgerock.openam.core.resource.lookup.cache.enabled*, to *false* in ***Configuration > Servers and Sites > Server Name > Advanced*** to see in real time your modify, but in a Production Environment remember to change again to true for better performance.

Best regards,
Alex